# UITableView reloadData duplicate cell

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

Having a bit of trouble getting "reloadData" to work with a UITableView. In short; if I add data / rows to the table, the rows will add, but show as duplicates of the existing rows. If I debug "DequeueReusableCell" it seems to just return a random cell. Here is my code. (yes it's C# - monotouch, if you know the answer in Objective-C, just post it, I'm flexible)

```
public partial class MyViewController : UITableViewController
{
    AppDelegate AppDelegate;
    MyStuff sendToDetail;
    MyRestClient client;

    public MyViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        AppDelegate = (AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate;
        client = new MyRestClient();
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        this.TableView.Source = new TableSource(getMyStuff (), this);
    }

    public override void PrepareForSegue (UIStoryboardSegue segue, NSObject sender)
    {
        base.PrepareForSegue (segue, sender);

        if (segue.Identifier == "DetailSegue") {
            DetailController controller = segue.DestinationViewController as DetailController;
            controller.MyStuffItem = sendToDetail;
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<MyStuff> getMyStuff(int skip = 0, int count = 10)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest("MyStuff");
        request.AddParameter("id", AppDelegate.ActiveUser.Id);
        request.AddParameter("$top", count);
        request.AddParameter("$skip", skip);
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        var source = (IEnumerable<MyStuff>)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content, typeof(IEnumerable<MyStuff>));

        return source;
    }

    public class TableSource : UITableViewSource {
        IEnumerable<MyStuff> tableItems;
        MyViewController Controller;

        public TableSource (IEnumerable<MyStuff> items, MyViewController controller)
        {
            tableItems = items;
            Controller = controller;
        }

        public override int NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        public override int RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, int section)
        {
            return tableItems.Count() + 1;
        }

        public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {

            if (indexPath.Row == tableItems.Count()) {
                //bottom load more cell

                LoadingCell loadMore = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("LoadingCell") as LoadingCell;
                if (loadMore == null)
                    loadMore = LoadingCell.Create ();

                return loadMore;
            }

            MyStuffCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("MyStuffCell") as MyStuffCell;
            // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
            if (cell == null) {
                cell = MyStuffCell.Create ();

                MyStuff current = tableItems.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);

                cell.Update (current);
            }

            return cell;
        }

        public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (indexPath.Row != tableItems.Count()) {
                Controller.sendToDetail = tableItems.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);
                Controller.PerformSegue ("DetailSegue", this);
            }
        }

        public override void WillDisplay (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            if (cell is LoadingCell) {
                var count = tableItems.Count ();
                var second = Controller.getMyStuff (count);
                tableItems = tableItems.Concat (second);
                tableView.ReloadData ();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The magic happens in `WillDisplay`. Here I check if it is going to display a `LoadingCell` (bottom one with a loading indicator) and will load the extra data accordingly and add it to my IEnumerable. Then after calling `reloadData` it will go into `GetCell` and `DequeueReusableCell` returns a duplicate...even for a "new" cell...

I removed everything that isn't part of the problem, so true enough: There is no error handling in my `getMyStuff` method, neither does it seem like I have any caching in place...otherwise I'm open to *best practice* comments.

I'm sure it is something incredible simple, but I just can't wrap my head around it. I've seen the other similar questions here on StackOverflow, but none provides a clear answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DequeueReusableCell just returns an allocated Cell object from it's internal cache.  You still need to update the contents of the cell to reflect whatever is appropriate for that Section/Row.

```
        MyStuffCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("MyStuffCell") as MyStuffCell;
        // if there are no cells to reuse, create a new one
        if (cell == null) {
            cell = MyStuffCell.Create ();
        }

        MyStuff current = tableItems.ElementAt (indexPath.Row);
        cell.Update (current);

        return cell;
```

Comment: I've obviously misunderstood the way DequeueReusableCell works. I am doing some additional loading and calculations in "Update", which I hoped to "cache" this way, but that's obviously not gonna happen. So basically the only use of DequeueReusableCell is to make sure that there's always a limited number of allocated cells in memory?

Comment: Right.  Rather than Dispose and create cells as you scroll, it just caches them, so you don't have to deal with the overhead of creating them constantly.  But the cell you get back may have old data in it from a different row, so you need to be sure to update it's contents.

Comment: Ok, that also explains the "static" identifier, which I neither understood :) Learned something new today. Thanks heaps